# How to identify ASP.NET web forms and ASP.NET MVC websites?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to find if a site developed by `ASP.NET` `MVC` or `ASP.NET` `web forms` ?

I want to find if [this](http://www.check4jobs.com/) site developed by `ASP.NET MVC` or `ASP.NET` web forms.

Comment: Web sites produce HTML. There's no way to tell one generator of HTML from another. Not for sure.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551857/how-do-i-identify-an-asp-net-mvc-website

Comment: From the `ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContentHome_rptLinkList_ctl04_aSearch"`, it looks like Webforms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally a webform application have few things like

- `<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />`
- `<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />`
- `<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="viewStateData" />`

Also to be considered most of the elements in the pages have

- Name looks like `ctl00$childControl$childControl$anyName`
- ID looks like `ctl00_childControl_childControl_anyName`

And definitely there will be block like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];

function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

And for ASP.NET MVC, [How do I identify an ASP.NET MVC website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551857/how-do-i-identify-an-asp-net-mvc-website)

Answer (score 2):

That site is Web Forms, it has the telltale webform IDs, e.g. `ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContentHome_rptLinkList_ctl20_aSearch`

Answer (score 1):

Since the links for some of the pages are aspx's the site (or at least the bits I looked at) are web forms.

Note also the strange control ids in some places which look like asp.net web forms controls (i.e. auto generated ids).

Comment: This may not always work.  People could be using the routing engine to append the .aspx to the routes to make MVC work in IIS 6 without using the wildcard mapping option.  My 2 pennies...